# JMeter page redirect error general

Tags: jmeter

I received this error when running my script.  The web site has a shopping cart on another site that gets information passed to it.  When running my script in JMeter, I received an error:

"1|#||4|31|pageRedirect||%2ferror.aspx%3ferror%3dgeneral|"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set "Use multipart/form-data for POST" for this http call in JMeter and then that error went away.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: It was helpful! :) Thanks!